# how to use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS() in same query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySql and I have a situation where i want to return the count of all of the rows from table and returning some rows by using limit in same query. I tried many things but i am not able to do it. please help me

let suppose my table is : **Student**

```
id | name | category |  gender
1    'A'    'Just'      'male'
2    'B'    'Just'      'Female'
3    'C'    'Just'      'male'
4    'D'    'Just'      'Female'
5    'E'    'Just'      'male'
```

**Output**:

```
id | name | category | gender | rcount
1    'A'    'Just'      'male'   5
2    'B'    'Just'      'Female' 5
3    'C'    'Just'      'male'   5
```

I want the above output from a single query please help me ?

Comment: To execute both in single statement is not possible as 2 mysql query can not be run in single statement expecting writing sub-query which will again considered as 2 queries

Comment: i tried writing sub query using table alias as well but it is not giving correct output. you can try

Comment: Pardon for my previous comment, you will first have to execute SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and afterward you can do SELECT FOUND_ROWS() this is one way, another you may avoid FOUND_ROWS() and just use simple count(*) so that may get you both result in single query

Comment: np Rupal, Thanks alot for your quick reply. could you please give(write the query with count(*) in a single query)your second option. i have tried this but in this case  count is correct but i am getting only one row which is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Rupal, the query which you have written it is the same as P.Salmon suggested earlier. i can not use this

Comment: Krishna I think you are going to have to accept that this cannot be done in a single query and push back on whoever is insisting you can.

Comment: P Salmon yes i think so . anyway thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

@Krishna find query below:

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, (select count(*) from student) as rcount from student limit 3;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/*
create table student (id int, name char(2), category char(4),  gender char(6));
insert into student values
(1 ,   'A' ,   'Just'  ,    'male'),
(2 ,   'B' ,   'Just'  ,    'Female'),
(3 ,   'C' ,   'Just'  ,    'male'),
(4 ,   'D' ,   'Just'  ,    'Female'),
(5 ,   'E' ,   'Just'  ,    'male');
*/
select  *,(select count(*) from student) as rcount
from    student
limit 3
```

Comment: Thanks P.Salmon, your query output is correct but i don't want to execute same query twice